# Apache client http5 override body & content-length problem

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

Prior to http5, i use HttpRequestInterceptor to override Entity, to sign request, ect ... with apache thrif calls (to evict override Thttpclient from libthrift)

With http5, interceptor have a new argument on interceptor method, EntityDetails, and it use on org.apache.hc.core5.http.protocol.RequestContent interceptor to set content-length header

But, entity has been overrided before ... and entity argument is now obsolete and all my request are now send with bad content-length.

Is this a bug ?
Or is there an other method with http5 to override entity/body ? (here sign request with certificate)

** workaround with a last interceptor to override content-length is ok

Answer (score 0):

Generally one ought not **//self-censored//** around with `Cotnent-Length` and let HttpClient generate it based on the entity details. If one needs to modify the message body one should be using a custom execution interceptor instead. [This example](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.3.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientInterceptors.java) may serve as a reasonable starting point